# Why Does This Groovy MetaClass Statement Work with Sql class?

Tags: sql, unit-testing, grails, groovy, junit

Why does this line of unit test code work?  groovy.sql.Sql doesn't have a no argument constructor.

```
Sql.metaClass.constructor = { dataSource -> return new Sql(); }
```

That line is amongst some others in a grails app which mocks out a Sql object's constructor and one of its methods. It works great.

Looking at the API for the Sql object, I do not see a no argument constructor: http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html

This style of overriding the constructor using Sql.metaClass.constructor is something I found at:
http://manuel-palacio.blogspot.com/2010/07/groovy-tip-metaprogramming-1.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`groovy.sql.Sql` has no public no-args constructor, but [as can be seen in the source](https://svn.codehaus.org/groovy/trunk/groovy/groovy-core/src/main/groovy/sql/Sql.java), it does have a private no-args constructor -- I guess in order to support the syntax `new Sql(connection: connection)`?.

I'm kind of surprised, though, that that technique for stubbing doesn't generate an exception, e.g., when running `sql.execute` or the like.

Comment: Nice! Thank you for the convenient link to the source too!

Comment: Instead of changing the constructor, I found I can set the DataSource into the service. Implementing the DataSource interface is easy and small using the "as DataSource". See http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+way+to+implement+interfaces where it says "as X"

Comment: Groovy 1.7 also supports anonymous inner classes. Work best with a recent release though (e.g. 1.7.6).